# How do I get the owners of all the guilds in discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the owner of all the guilds my bot is in, so I can send a newsletter to them. So far I have this:

```js
const guilds = message.client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild);
guilds.forEach(guild => {
    const owner = message.client.users.cache.get(guild.ownerId)
    owner.send({embeds: [newsembed]})
    .catch(console.error());
});
```

which gets the guilds, then gets the owner id, then gets the owner from the id in the cache. Now normally I would use `.fetchOwner()` but I cannot use await it in a forEach loop, but if you have a suggestion for that please do tell. When running the code listed above I get the error:

```
            owner.send({embeds: [newsembed]})
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

I am not sure why I get this error, maybe the owner is not in the cache? I have tried fetching them in a forEach loop but I cant use `await guild.fetchOwner()` in forEach loops. I tried putting the forEach loop in an async function, same problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `forEach()` loop asynchronous

```js
const guilds = message.client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild);
guilds.forEach(async guild => {
    const owner = await guild.fetchOwner();
    owner.send({embeds: [newsembed]})
       .catch(console.error());
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! Now the only problem is when it finds someone it cant send a message to, it crashes despite the .catch bit, ill probably put the foreach loop in a try catch block.

Comment: Can I do async loops in try catch blocks?

Comment: Try voiding the error catch: `.catch(() => null)` or yes wrapping a try/catch around the *sending of the message* and `return` if the catch block executes. Make sure you `await` any promises inside a try/catch block

Comment: Alright, I have put the try catch around the *sending* **inside** the `forEach` loop, there aren't any promises inside the try catch so I don't need to `await` anything.

Comment: Sending a message returns a promise, if you want the errors to be caught within the try/catch you'll need to await it

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try that, thanks again!